# 'RequiredAttribute' is an ambiguous reference with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using EF model first in MVC, I have problems with this error:

> 'RequiredAttribute' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute' and
>   'ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute

I can not use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and `ServiceStack.DataAnnotations`. I need to Both of them for Indexing Column and also Requiring Column

I am not able to find the solution for this.

Comment: Did you try `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]` or `[ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.Required]` ?

Comment: Thank for ur Answer
I use

using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[Required]` attribute and add `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]` and `[ServiceStack.DataAnnotations.Required]` respectively so that the ambiguity is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]` instead of `[Required]`